# wix XmlConfig syntax

Tags: wix, wix3.5

I need to modify machine.config during installation procedure. I know, that I need to use XMLConfig component, but still not everything is clear for me:

- As I figured out, util:XmlConfig tag should be placed inside Component tag. Component tag should be placed inside Directory tag. Should I create Directory definition tag with unique ID on purpose to use with util:XmlConfig? Can you provide very minimal sample with entire component and directory definition I should use in my case to make me understand how this really works?
- I need to modify machine.config file, path is like this:
  File="[WindowsFolder]Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\CONFIG\Machine.Config".
  But is this good idea to provide path like this? Maybe I rather should get this path automatically (I mean .net framework version number) - is this possible?
- I need to add entry DbProviderFactories in machine.config. What if entries I want to add are already present in file? They will be added again, replaced? If they will be added twice, how can I prevent this?

Comment: You sure you need to modify machine.config?  You can put your DbProviderFactory settings in your web.config or app.config file...  Makes it easier to accomplish this using XmlConfig.

Comment: I need to modify machine.config bacause app crashes when I register provider locally.

Answer (score 0):

If all you need (as I guess) is to make use of Entity Framework, you should not modify the machine.config file. This can be dangerous, as you may unintentionally render it inconsistent.

Instead, you can do the following trick:

1. Get the config data, that is already read by CLR:

   ```
   var dataSet = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.data") as System.Data.DataSet;
   ```
2. Then check first table and third column in this table for your provider's invariant name:

   ```
   bool bFound = false;
   foreach (DataRow row in dataSet.Tables[0].Rows)
   {
           if (row[2].ToString() == "EFOracleProvider")
           {
                bFound = true;
                break;
           }
   }
   // if this provider is not already listed in the table, then add it
   // set oracle provider parameters
   if (!bFound)
   {
          dataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Add(
                   provName,
                   provDesc,
                   provInvariant,
                   provAssembly
           );
   }
   ```

Of course, you should do it **before** first ObjectContext creation.

Comment: For some reason, it works only when connector is registered globally. If I register in code or in app.config, always application crashes. This is probably related to wpf data bindings in resource and I have no idea how to fix this (and have no time to figure it out). So I decided to register connector globally - I've tried to edit machine.config manually and it worked.